# Why doesn't this code work? (on HTML format)

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't this code work? My visual studio code is telling me that the "else" in 
"else if" has declaration or statement expected.
my script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 1+1;
var y = 1.5*2
if (a = 2){
for (var i = 0; i<5; i = i + 2){
    document.write("Hello "+ i +" Everyone.</br>")
} else if (y=3){
for (var j = 2; j < 10; j = j+3){
    document.write("Hey there.")
}
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwc1c.png

Answer (score 7):

Your code didn't work for a couple of reasons:

- When comparing a variable to a number you have to use either == or === (compare value and compare value / type).
- You forgot to close off the tags for your first for loop.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 1+1;
var y = 1.5*2

if (a === 2) {
  for (var i = 0; i<5; i = i + 2) {
    document.write("Hello "+ i +" Everyone.</br>")
   }
} else if (y === 3) {
  for (var j = 2; j < 10; j = j+3){
    document.write("Hey there.")
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ooh! I forgot to close the bracket of the if statement :/ Thank you!

Comment: No problem! It would be awesome if you marked this as the solution if it all worked!